# Printf() function acting strange

Tags: c++

Apologies if this question is stupid, I'm new to coding, especially in C++. I'm trying to read in data points from a space-separated text and then use the printf function to get it output them to the console. When I try this;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    double x[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    double y[1000];
    double sigmay[1000];

    ifstream dataFile("xys_test.txt");

    if (dataFile.is_open()) {
        while (!dataFile.eof())
        dataFile >> x[i] >> y[i] >> sigmay[i];
        printf("x = %5.2f, y = %5.2f, sigmay = %5.2f\n", x[i], y[i], sigmay[i]);
    i++;
}
}
```

All the console output gives me is the last data point, when I was hoping that all the points would be output into the console. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you not using `cout` instead of `printf` in C++ code?

Comment: Also missing braces. Add then after the line that starts `while`

Comment: you must `#include <cstdio>` to use printf

Comment: lesson #1 in C++ file i/o: [never use `eof` in a loop condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: the body of your `while` loop is only a single line

Comment: Make it a habit to use braces whenever possible. It prevents one from getting caught with your trousers down :-)

Comment: If I replace `printf` directly with ` cout << ` I only get the last value of the sigmay array

Comment: .. And replace the commas with << - Please read the text book on iostreams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a pair of `{ ... }` for the contents of your `while` block. Currently, only the `dataFile >> x[i] >> y[i] >> sigmay[i];` line is inside the `while` block.

```
if (dataFile.is_open()) {
    while (!dataFile.eof()) {
        dataFile >> x[i] >> y[i] >> sigmay[i];
        printf("x = %5.2f, y = %5.2f, sigmay = %5.2f\n", x[i], y[i], sigmay[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you lost your curly bracket,

```
while (!dataFile.eof()) {
  dataFile >> x[i] >> y[i] >> sigmay[i];
  printf("x = %5.2f, y = %5.2f, sigmay = %5.2f\n", x[i], y[i], sigmay[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted and removed my answer as this was more clear than mine.

Answer (score 2):

The code should be:

```
while ( i < 1000 && (dataFile >> x[i] >> y[i] >> sigmay[i]) )
{
    printf("x = %5.2f, y = %5.2f, sigmay = %5.2f\n", x[i], y[i], sigmay[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

You should test whether or not the read operation succeeded, in order to decide whether to proceed with printing and committing the data.  Testing [eof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is irrelevant and a mistake.

Also `#include <cstdio>` should be used for `printf`. Possibly your compiler/library setup involves cstdio being included by iostream but in general that is not the case.